# Show Javadoc after pressing ctrl + space in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, popup, javadoc

Is there any way, to display Javadoc popup in Eclipse in "Netbeans way"? Example: When I write Str and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> I'd like to see popup with proposals (String, StringMath, StringBuffer and so on) and another window with Javadoc for highlighted proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse does support showing documentation of a highlighted element when you are using ctrl + space for autocompleting. However to have that working you need to do a little set up for the jre/jdk you are using to show eclipse where to look for the docs.

You can do that by checking out Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > then edit the JRE / JDK you've there. you basically have  two options either setting the JavaDoc location or the Source attachement.